# How can I do Join in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, select, join

How can I do JOIN in codeigniter? Im just a newbie in programming using codeigniter.

I have 2 tables an item_db table and a mob_db table.

```
item_db table:
+-----+---------------+
| id  | name          |
+-----+---------------+
| 501 | Red Potion    |
+-----+---------------+
| 502 | Orange Potion |
+-----+---------------+
| 503 | Green Potion  |
+-----+---------------+

mob_db table:
+------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| ID   | Drop1id | Drop1per | Drop2id | Drop2per |
+------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| 1001 | 501     | 7000     |         |          |
+------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| 1002 | 502     | 500      | 503     | 2500     |
+------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| 1003 | 501     | 7000     | 502     | 500      |
+------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
```

how can I change the variable into the name that is match in item_db?
If I got the variable 501 from mob_db, how can I change it into a name that match in item_db table as well as the percentage which is the Drop1per or Drop2per or Drop3per?

Example:
501 - 1000%
502 - 500%
503 - 2500%

Result must be:
Red Potion - 10%
Orage Potion - 5%
Green Potion - 25%

I hope you understood my issue. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the SQL that you have written.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `item_db` (
  `id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: CREATE TABLE `mob_db` (
  `ID` mediumint(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Drop1id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Drop1per` smallint(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Drop2id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Drop2per` smallint(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: Please help me. Im jut new to this.

Comment: Do you understand how to do joins at all?